# Android: Determine when an Activity has finished animating in to view?

Tags: android

I'm trying to determine when an Activity has finished animating in to view on Android? The callback Activity.onStart() is called when an Activity is first added to the view hierarchy, but I can't seem to find a callback that happens the 300 milliseconds or so later when the activity has finished animating into view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `onWindowFocusChanged()` of the `Activity` class. You can do something like

```
void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        // do stuff you want to when activity becomes visible.
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be the answer although it's hard to tell. It appears that onWindowFocusChanged is called ~25 ms after onCreate(), although that seems like a very short amount of time for the animation to have occured.